# ASM HelloWorld program

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att, gnu-assembler

Im trying to write my first asm program. Here's the code of my program so far;

```
.data
    hello: .string "Hello World!!!!\n"
    format: .string "%s\n"
.text
    .global _start
    _start:

    push hello
    push format
    call printf

    movl $1, %eax   #exit
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

> Segmentation fault.

Comment: You should pop the arguments after `printf` returns (e.g. using `add esp,8`).

Comment: `add %esp, 8 ` did not help.

Comment: `push $hello` and `push $format` should fix you up.

Comment: Does that code even assemble? You've mixed Intel and AT&T syntax.

Comment: Yes, this would assemble, and old GAS version wouldn't even warn about the ambiguous operand-size for `push [mem]`, e.g. `pushl hello` loads 4 bytes of ASCII data from that address, instead of pushing the address.  So yes it's sort of mixing Intel and AT&T syntax, but it's unfortunately still valid AT&T syntax that means something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
.att_syntax
.global main
.section .data
     txt: .asciz "Hello World"
.section .text
     mov $4, %eax
     mov $1, %ebx
     mov $txt, %ecx
     mov $11, %edx
     int $0x80
     ret
```